# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, class

I am trying to download a dynamic JSON from a site to the var Vjson.
deserialize it and show some content to the console.
I don't know what I am doing wrong. I receive a NullReferenceException error however I am sure there is data.

```
        {
                var client = new WebClient();
                var Vjson = client.DownloadString(Some URL);
                dynamic Post = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( Vjson);
                foreach (var item in Post.Match)  //loop through class    //Post Match error System.NullReferenceException
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} \n", item.ip_str, item.port);
            }
```

The class is

```
   class Post
 
    {

        public class Location
        {

            public string city { get; set; }
            ....
            public string country_name { get; set; }

        }

        public class Options
        {

        }

        public class Scodder
        {
            public string crawler { get; set; }
            ...
            public Options options { get; set; }
        }

        public class AngularJS
        {
            public IList<string> categories { get; set; }
        }

        public class Components
        {
            public AngularJS AngularJS { get; set; }
        }

        public class Http
        {
            public int? robots_hash { get; set; }
            ....
            public string waf { get; set; }
        }
        public class Match                      // Post.Match
        {
            ...
            public int port { get; set; }        //---- data i try to extract 
            ....
            public string ip_str { get; set; }   //---- data i try to extract 
            ...
        }
        public IList<Match> matches { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please provide the json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
foreach (var item in Post.matches)
```

instead of

```
foreach (var item in Post.Match)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public List<Match> matches { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
public IList<Match> matches { get; set; }
```

Also

```
foreach (var item in Post.Match)
```

But you have no such collection, you have collection `public IList<Match> matches { get; set; }`

Try this instead

```
foreach (var item in Post.matches)
```

And why cant you use generic version of deserialization?

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Post>(Vjson)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the json string is not provided and so without any debugging
I can think of 2 changes

Add a parameterless public constructor in the Post class

```
class Post
{
    public Post()
    {
    }
}
```

and secondly deserialize the json string like below

```
var x1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Post>(Vjson);
```